# Livewire wire:model on custom component

Tags: laravel-livewire

Say you got a livewire component for a customly styles checkbox like this:

```
@props(['checked' => false])
<div x-data="{checked: @entangle($attributes->get('wire:model'))}">
    <input id="{{ $attributes->get('wire:model') ?? $uuid = uniqid('', true) }}" class="hidden"
           type="checkbox"
        {{ $attributes->except('class') }}
    >
    <label :class="checked ? 'text-gray-100 shadow-inner' : ''"
           for="{{ $attributes->get('wire:model') ?? $uuid }}"
           class="group-checked:border-2 border-white w-8 h-8 p-3 bg-gray-700 text-gray-400 font-serif tracking-widest text-xl font-bold cursor-pointer select-none shadow-gray-100 rounded">TT</label>
</div>
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to access the value from the wire:model binding inside of the wrapping div? I now solved it with the @entangle magic, but that feels a bit strange since i am used to vue, and in vue you could access a property called "value" (by default) to access the bound input value.

If that was possible by say a magically injected $value variable, i would be able to get rid of the x-data attribute right?

How are you guys solving this?

Answer (score 0):

wire:model watches the `input` event. You can customly emit an `input` event from the livewire component side.

Comment: I'm not talking about emitting to the outside of the component. I'm taling about "receiving" a value from the outside

Comment: I said it due to the title of your question, have you tried $attributes->get('value'), or in your case for checkbox $attributes->get('checked') using laravel's component? (you need to create a custom x-checkbox then)